# Erro ao tentar passar um struct por referência em C?

Tags: c

Estou tendo aula de ponteiros e estou tentando fazer o seguinte exercicio:

Considere um cadastro de alunos matriculados em uma disciplina, com as seguintes informações para cada aluno:

• Nome do aluno: com até 80 caracteres
• Número de matrícula: representado por um valor inteiro
• Notas obtidas em três provas, P1, P2, P3: representadas por valores reais

(a) Defina uma estrutura em C, denominada aluno, que tenha os campos apropriados para guardar as informações de um aluno, conforme descrito acima.
(b) Escreva uma função que receba como parâmetro um ponteiro para uma estrutura do tipo definido no item anterior e imprima na tela do computador uma linha com o nome do aluno e outra linha com a média obtida nas três provas. Essa função deve seguir o seguinte protótipo:

```
void imprime (struct aluno* a);
```

Só que está dando erro no código:

```
'#include stdio.h'
'#include stdlib.h'

void imprime(struct aluno *a);

int main()
{
    struct aluno{
        char aluno[80];
        int mat;
        float p1,p2,p3;
    } joao;

    printf("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
    gets(joao.aluno);

    printf("Digite a matricula do aluno: ");
    scanf("%i", &joao.mat);

    printf("Digite as notas do aluno:\n" );
    scanf("%d %d %d", &joao.p1,&joao.p2,&joao.p3);

    imprime(&joao);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

void imprime(struct aluno* a){
    printf("%s",a->nome);
}
```

O erro é o seguinte:

```
ERRO: |28|error: conflicting types for 'imprime'|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na primeira vez que o compilador encontra a funcao `imprime()` ele ainda nao encontrou a definicao de `struct aluno`.

Depois, dentro da funcao `main()` aparece a definicao da `struct aluno`; que tem efeito a partir dai ate ao fim do programa.

Na segunda vez que aparece a funcao `imprime()`, o compilador tem outra ideia do que é a `struct aluno`.

Ou seja, para o compilador ha duas `struct aluno` diferentes (com o mesmo nome) e ele queixa-se.

A solucao melhor é passar a definicao da `struct aluno` para antes de qualquer uso; para imediatamente a seguir aos `#include`s.

Comment: Exatamente isso, mt obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Analisando seu código, sugiro:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct aluno{
    char aluno[80];
    int mat;
    float p1,p2,p3;
} joao;

void imprime(struct aluno *a);

int main()
{
    printf("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
    gets(joao.aluno);

    printf("Digite a matricula do aluno: ");
    scanf("%i", &joao.mat);

    printf("Digite as notas do aluno:\n" );
    scanf("%d %d %d", &joao.p1,&joao.p2,&joao.p3);

    imprime(&joao);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

void imprime(struct aluno* a){
    printf("%s",a->aluno);
}
```